# Partial view JavaScript running multiple times when loaded in Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, partial-views

I have following HTML for modal

```
<div id="mdEdit" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="overflow:hidden;" data-width="800">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div>
                <img src="/Content/images/ico-cross.png" style="cursor:pointer; margin:10px; float:right" class="" data-dismiss="modal" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="padding:25px;" id="mdbEdit">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use following script to load Partial view in it

```
function EditFile(gridId, fileID, ctrl) {
            var grid = $('#grid_' + gridId).data("kendoGrid");
            var dataItem = $("tr", grid.tbody).index($(ctrl).closest("tr"));
            $.ajax({
                url: "/I9Roster/EditFileAjax?Id=" + fileID + "&dataItemNo=" + dataItem + "&gridId=grid_" + gridId,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {

                    $('#mdEdit').modal('toggle');
                    $('#mdbEdit').html(data);

                }
            });
        }
```

The issue I am facing is that I have a list of items on main page and clicking on button which loads modal one by one for some items runs javascript in partial view the number of times modal has pop out. e.g. suppose I click on first item and modal is opened with partial view and javascript runs only once, then I close this modal and click on other item to open the modal with same partial view. Now the javascript runs two times as the partial view was loaded two times. This continues to be happening number of times partial view is loaded in modal. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved here by placing the `<div>` containg the id that will be rewritten by the javascript on the Main Page, instead of the Partial View.

In your case, the Partial View containing the Modal will look like this:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div>
            <img src="/Content/images/ico-cross.png" style="cursor:pointer; margin:10px; float:right" class="" data-dismiss="modal" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="padding:25px;" id="mdbEdit">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following div should be placed in the Main Page:

```
<div id="mdEdit" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="overflow:hidden;" data-width="800">
```

Comment: Please also explain, why that works. It is always nice to get a solution to a question, but since programming is usually about understanding what you do, it is way better to explain how to solve a problem instead of just doing it.

Comment: I have to say it was pure intuition. I had done some research but haven´t been able to teel why this works.